# Tricky regex issue, matching a value in a line beginning with keyword

Tags: regex, perl, file, expression

I am trying to search a text file for a certain keyword, and match that keyword when the line that it is contained in starts with a certain value: For instance, I am trying to match instances of "bar" when those instances occur in lines that start with "foo". For example:

```
foo dum diddly bar dee
hello world bar hopping
foo how bar you
foo jingle jangle jingle
```

Line one and three should match, however lines two and four should not match. I have tried using the lookbehind operator like this: `/(?<=^foo)bar/` , specifically using the `^` operator in order to attempt to match the beginning of the line, however this does not work. I have also tested it without the `^` and with and without `\b` around foo and bar in an attempt to isolate where the regex is going wrong. For reference I am using perl, and here is what the entirety of my code looks like:

```
use 5.14.2;
use strict;
use warnings;
open(my $fh, "<", "perltest.txt") or die "$!";
while(my $line = <$fh>)
{
    if($line =~ /(?<=^foo)bar/)
    {
        print "succeeded\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "failed\n"
    }
}
print "finished\n";
```

I am getting failures to match on all of these lines. It doesn't appear to be an issue with my code, as I can successfulyl get matches with more basic regex evaluations, so I am fairly certain the issue lies with the lookbehind. I have tried regex101 to no avail as well. If anyone has any advice on how to create a successful regex for this, it would be incredible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    print if m/^foo.*\bbar\b/
}

__DATA__
foo dum diddly bar dee
hello world bar hopping
foo how bar you
foo jingle jangle jingle
```

Prints:

```
foo dum diddly bar dee
foo how bar you
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match:

```
/^(?=foo\b).*?\b(bar)\b.*/gm
```

And extract the matched value with `$1` (group 1)

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nX6cI0/2)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you desire output:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fh, "<", "perltest.txt") or die "$!";

while(my $line = <$fh>)
{
    if($line =~ /^foo.*\bbar\b/)
    {
        print "$line";
    }
}

_____DATA_____
foo dum diddly bar dee
hello world bar hopping
foo how bar you
foo jingle jangle jingle
```

Output:

```
foo dum diddly bar dee
foo how bar you
```